# How to write .htaccess to target subdomain?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

The website home page is working as expected but the whole website is redirects me to **parking page** would anyone help me out to solve this issue will be great and thankfull.

```
like sub.domain.co.uk and path is /dir1/mywebsite
```

here is my **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase    /
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you want to redirect all or some specific urls to `/dir/website` ?

Comment: I want to target my whole website to /dir/website

Comment: If you want the domain to point to another folder, just change the document root-folder in your webservers vhost?

Answer (score 0):

You can add following code your .htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 "/old-directory" "http://www.new.com/new-directory"
```

Please refer this for more details :

[Reference here](https://wpscholar.com/blog/simple-redirects-with-htaccess/)

Comment: Thanks every one who helped me to resolve this issue. 
The line below has resolved my issue ...
    
    **RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).+)$ /index.php [L]**